# Removing the link/constriants between the StackLayoutView and its child view in IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I am developing an IOS game. Really basic and simple game as a learning purpose because I just started learning IOS development. My game is a simple car racing game, user will move his or her car dragging an image and other car will keep spawning from the top. When they hit each others, the game ends. As you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

Now, I can drag the car and detect the collision with the other cars as well. The problem now I can drag my car to the anywhere in the screen. What I am trying to do now is put the road image in to a stack layout view and crop the background image to get only road. Then set the road image as background to the stack layout view. Then set the main screen background to green. So user can move his or her car only in the stack view.  Now I am adding the stack view into the main view.
I set the stack view's size the same as the main view setting the constriant like this.

[image]

When I add that four constriants, the car image also become the full screen size. When I change the car image, the stack view is resized the same size as the car. So my question is how can I use the stack view as the group layout view, not as a wrapper, removing that size contriants? For example like linearlayout in android.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest different strategy here. You can set main view to be green and then add another UIImageView on top of it (with the road image asset). Your car could be another image view which could have pan gesture on it, and you could set a restriction programmatically so it doesn't "leave" the road.

```
func didPan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    //calculating new car position
    let fingerPosition = gesture.location(in: view)
    let minPosition = roadImageView.frame.origin.x + carImageView.frame.size.width / 2
    let maxPosition = roadImageView.frame.maxX - carImageView.frame.size.width / 2
    var carCenterX = max(fingerPosition.x, minPosition)
    carCenterX = min(carCenterX, maxPosition)
    carImageView.center = CGPoint(x: carCenterX, y: fingerPosition.y)
}
```